# How to make dashed Line in ggplot? It does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a problem with the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQFde.png) legend.

The dashed lines in the plot are not dashed in the legend, even though I defined their style with the command: scale_linetype_manual I want to show the second year inputs as dashed lines.

```
gg <- ggplot()
    
    if ("Min" %in% selected_metrics) {
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year1_A, aes(x = month, y = Min, color = "Min - Year 1"), size = 1, linetype = "solid", show.legend = TRUE)
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year2_A, aes(x = month, y = Min, color = "Min - Year 2"), linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
      
    }
    if ("Mean" %in% selected_metrics) {
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year1_A, aes(x = month, y = Mean, color = "Mean - Year 1"), size = 1, linetype = "solid")
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year2_A, aes(x = month, y = Mean, color = "Mean - Year 2"), linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
      
    }
    if ("Max" %in% selected_metrics) {
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year1_A, aes(x = month, y = Max, color = "Max - Year 1"), size = 1, linetype = "solid")
      gg <- gg + geom_line(data = monthly_temperatures_year2_A, aes(x = month, y = Max, color = "Max - Year 2"), linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
      
    }
    
    gg <- gg +
      labs(
        x = 'Month',
        y = 'Temperature',
        title = paste("Monthly", paste(selected_metrics, collapse = "/"), "Temperature Variation for", input$station)
      ) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month_labels) +
      scale_color_manual(
        name = "Variables",
        labels = c(paste("Min -", input$year1_A), paste("Min -", input$year2_A), paste("Mean -", input$year1_A), paste("Mean -", input$year2_A), paste("Max -", input$year1_A), paste("Max -", input$year2_A)),
        values = c("orange", "orange", "green", "green", "red", "red")
      ) +
      scale_linetype_manual(
        name = "Variables",
        labels = c(paste("Min -", input$year1_A), paste("Min -", input$year2_A), paste("Mean -", input$year1_A), paste("Mean -", input$year2_A), paste("Max -", input$year1_A), paste("Max -", input$year2_A)),
        values = c("solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed")
      ) +
      theme(legend.position = "right")
    
    print(gg)
  })
```

If anyone can help and suggest what codes should I use OR what should I change it would be really great! I am stucked. Thank you very much.

[image: plot]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? In your code I have no idea what `gg`, `selected_metrics`, `monthly_temperatures_year1_A`, or `monthly_temperatures_year2_A` look like. Try  to create a simple reproducible example that uses a built-in dataset like `mtcars` and you'll get better answers!

Comment: If the mapping for `linetype=` is not inside the `aes()`, you will not get a legend for it. ggplot only created legends for things inside `aes()`.

Comment: My guess, lacking sample data: combine `monthly_temperatures_year1_A` and `monthly_temperatures_year2_A`, making sure that there is a `year` column in both frames so that you can distinguish between them. From there, reduce your two `geom_line` calls down to one, using `geom_line(aes(... linetype=year))`, and then `scale_linetype_manual(values=c("2020"="solid", "2022"="dashed"))` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
year1 <- data.frame(x = factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb), y = runif(12), z = factor(sample(3, size=12, replace=TRUE)))
year2 <- data.frame(x = factor(month.abb, levels=month.abb), y = year1$y + 0.02, z = year1$z)
```

Broken plot:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = year1, mapping = aes(x, y, color = z, group = z), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = year2, mapping = aes(x, y, color = z, group = z), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image: broken ggplot]

Fix:

```r
years <- dplyr::bind_rows(year1, year2, .id = "year")
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = years, mapping = aes(x, y, color = z, group = interaction(z, year), linetype = factor(year))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("1"="solid", "2"="dashed"))
```

[image: fixed ggplot]

I like the use of `dplyr::bind_rows(...)` here because in my sample data, there is no inherent "year" distinguishing column. Similarly, `data.table::rbindlist(list(...), idcol="year")` does the same thing. They also (perhaps with options) support different set of columns or order of columns.

If each of your `year#` frames already has the requisite `"year"` column, and if all of them have the same columns and order of columns, you can get away with `years <- rbind(year1, year2)`.